# How to make initial setup for C++ development in VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I try to setup C++ for VS Code through YouTube videos, but they are quite old. So, there is a configuration error in **c_cpp_properties.json** and **task.json**.

Comment: Here is quite up-to-date (at the moment of writing this) and thorough video tutorial: [Set Up C++ Development With Visual Studio Code on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIw02CaEusY).

Comment: And here is the **official** Microsoft Visual Studio Code documentation about how to configure VS Code for C/C++: ► [Mingw on Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw), ► [GCC on Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl), ► [Clang on macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac), ► [Microsoft C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc).

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install [***MinGW-w64***](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)
2. Install the "*C/C++ for Visual Studio Code*" extension

This all setting for Window operating system. For other operation systems you have to change only *c_cpp_properties.json* [configuration](https://gist.github.com/GLaDOS1105/a2b6944bc46d1c1dd69e31be9fb0d0cd)

An example of *c_cpp_properties.json* file (you have to add your own *path* of MinGW-w64):

```json
{
    "configurations": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Win64",

            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0",
                "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0",
                    "C:\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 3
}
```

An example of *task.json* file:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "debug",
     "type": "shell",
            "command": "",
            "args": ["g++","-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o","a.exe"]
        },
        {
            "label": "Compile and run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "",
            "args": [
                "g++","-g", "${relativeFile}", "-o","${fileBasenameNoExtension}", "&&" , "./${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true  
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can build C++ programs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.